# When enabling Bluetooth, is there a way to prevent it from attempting to connect to the two most recently used devices?

Tags: bluetooth

Device: LG Nexus 4 (16 GB)

Android version: 4.2.2

I connect my phone via Bluetooth (A2DP) to three devices on a daily basis. Since Android only tries connecting with the two most recent devices, I have to go into the Bluetooth settings and manually select the device I actually want to connect to.

Also, while the first two are attempting a connection, I'm unable to select the third device. I have to wait until those connections fail before it lets me manually choose the other.

Have any of you found any ways to get around this or automate it?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ICS or Jelly Bean, there are free apps called [Bluetooth Auto Connect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.myklos.btautoconnect) and [Auto Bluetooth](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.solarwoodenrobot.autobluetooth) that will automatically connect to devices you specify. From the looks of it, it was designed because some devices don't auto connect to *any* Bluetooth devices (let alone two). It will likely work for your phone as well, if you are running Android 4.